QGIS Snapping on invisible(by scale) features
I using QGIS 3.34 (but in 3.36 same problem).
When I turn on snapping, it snaps to layers, which are invisible by scale. But it isn't snapping to features which are invisible by rules in style (and that's ok).
Visible feature (scale 1:500):

Same place on scale 1:1000: 
First I thought, that snap match didn't refreshed after scaling, but I moved mouse and still get snapping to invivsible feature.
I tried to look in snapping settings and found nothing.
I tried to setScaleDependencyMode to config in python code, but see no differnce.
Only solution I found is to look in layer style by python, and set same scale to snap settings. But I guess that is "hard way"
